# nginx - redirect a certain path to another domain

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

I am very unfamiliar with nginx, as a forewarning, and also can't find any actual references on the regex system they use. So right now it's a black box to me.

All I want to do is redirect a user trying to go to www.mydomain.com/mydirectory/X to www.myotherdomain.com/X .

Seems like I should be using the rewrite command but the syntax of the regex is eluding me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I made a solution that works. I had it before posting this question but didn't realize I needed to restart nginx. Put the following inside your server block.

```
rewrite ^(/mydirectory/)(.*)$ http://www.myotherdomain.com/$2 permanent;
```

Comment: No need to restart. Send HUP signal to it to reload configuration.