# Nginx rule for redirecting http://www.example.com/test to test.domain.com

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I need a small help in writing nginx rule for redirecting a subfolder to subdomain as shown below

http://www.example.com/test to test.domain.com

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [nginx - redirect a certain path to another domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017677/nginx-redirect-a-certain-path-to-another-domain)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the www.example.com virtual host just write this line in the config:

```
rewrite ^/test http://test.domain.com;
```