# Environment independent builds using the Vue webpack template

Tags: javascript, deployment, build, webpack, vue.js

I use a build server to build my Vue projects, using the `npm run build` command nicely supplied by the Vue 2 template.  The Vue template also provides the ability to access environment-specific data that can be configured in files underneath the `config` directory.  Things like `prod.env.js`, etc.  You then access this data through `process.env.API_PREFIX` as seen in the template manual.

I want to be able to build the code once, then deploy the same build (as defined by the output in `Dist`) to multiple servers, but have the different servers use different configuration (different `API_PREFIX` etc).  Currently, the `process.env` references are expanded at build time by the Webpack compiler.  Therefore I have to rebuild for every environment.

I can think of a few ways to do this -- obviously the loading of the config has to happen at runtime, and given that it runs in the browser and has to refer to some file, it would have to be through an AJAX request for some static JSON configuration served by the web server separately, or similar.  But I'd be interested to know how anyone here would handle this requirement.

Comment: There are a few tricks, but need more information on how do you determine the API_PREFIX. Is it related with the domain in which the application is going to be accessed at? Can you give concrete examples?

Comment: Yes, the API prefix is an example of configuration data that's specific to each environment.  It would be a different domain for each deployment environment.  For instance, in the build for the `staging` deployment environment, the API prefix might be `https://staging-api.mycompany.com`.  [it's not derivable in principle from the name of the environment, though.]

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your specific architecture is hard to give specific advice. Instead I will leave a few general ideas.

In order to do what you want in a sane way, you probably would have to derive the prefix from the domain in which you are serving the frontend.

There are a few things you can use for that, besides using `window.location` at runtime:

- Relative paths `/api/myinformation` - the prefix will be automatically derived from the domain where the frontend is served at.
- Local proxy during development, since you might not want to run the backend on localhost https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/master/docs/proxy.md
- Proxy path rewrite on nginx or similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3017720/1445812

Even if it doesn't solve your specific case, hope it gives you an idea of what available.

Comment: My question isn't really about the API prefix, which is just an incidental example of a piece of configuration that I want to parameterize after the build process.  I have many other things that are specific to the deployment environment that are unrelated to the prefix.  I need a general way to read configuration variables at runtime.

Comment: The question is where, when and how do you want to write them. Based on which criteria. Without a more specific description of the usecase, hard to give more specific ideas.

Comment: I think I've decided to do it using Webpack externals, a global script tag, and a file under `static` directory that defines the configuration on the `window` object.  This is evaluated at runtime but still brought into the webpack context in a way that appears synchronous.

Comment: Not sure what you gain by using webpack externals, besides including your file using a global script tag, since you are talking about of just a few variables, not an exiting package.

Comment: You're right that there's not a lot of real difference from simply accessing global configuration stored on `window` directly in the modules.  It just psychologically feels more clean to `import myconfig from 'my-config'` rather than referring to `window.myconfig` everywhere.

Comment: One could argue even that the code will be less readable because the origin of the variables will be obfuscated in the webpack configuration :)

Comment: This question also contained some useful ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777595/any-way-to-use-webpack-to-load-a-resource-at-runtime.  But it seems that the complexity from making this asynchronous load would outweigh any gains that I would get from it.